# How big is the Dogecoin blockchain as of 2018 Feb?

Tags: blockchain, dogecoin

What is the size of the Dogecoin blockchain as of 2018 Feb? And where would I find this data in cyberspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow that and other data on https://bitinfocharts.com/dogecoin/

Comment: It's 25.94 GB as of today.